# Swift Custom TabBar Icon in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, tabbar

Currently i m working on my first TabBar App and i want to add a custom icon to my tabbar, currently i only get a grey square and the icon is not shown.

I found some stuff i have to add in AppDelegate but this didn't helped for me, is there a way to use the "tag" to set a Enabled and a "non Enabled" image?

I m using a png with 20x30px image for this.
See screenshot

[image]

Anyone a idea whats wrong? What i have todo?

Answer (score 0):

Image did not have a transparent background ... this was the misstake